# AndroidBillingLibrary: Remote Service crashed on BillingController.requestPurchase

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm developing an application that will have some features that the user must pay to use. User can purchase in each activity by clicking button. To do this I use Android In-app billing and robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary. Everything seems to work fine on my devices: HTC Wildfire S (Android 2.3.5) and Asus Transformer Pad (Android 4.1.1) but I got information (with Log capture) that sometimes on other devices after clicking on buy button nothing happens.
The devices:

- Samsung Galaxy ACE (Android 2.3.5)
- HTC Sensation (Andorid 4.0.3)
- Xperia Neo V (Android 2.3.4)

Here is the Log capture:

```
11-30 15:05:16.157: D/Parent Activity:(30220): Request Purchase: myitem
11-30 15:05:16.177: W/BillingService(30220): Remote billing service crashed
11-30 15:05:16.177: W/BillingService(30220): Caused by: null
```

This is part of code from my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        (...)
        initViews();
        initBilling();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    BillingController.unregisterObserver(mBillingObserver);
    (...)
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initBilling()
{
    mBillingObserver = new BillingObserver(this);
    BillingController.registerObserver(mBillingObserver);
    BillingController.setConfiguration(new BillingConfiguration());
    BillingController.checkBillingSupported(getApplicationContext());
    if (!mBillingObserver.isTransactionsRestored()) {
        BillingController.restoreTransactions(getApplicationContext());
    }
    Settings.updateOwnedItems(this);
}

private void showPurchaseAlert()
{
    if(Settings.isOnline() && BillingController.checkBillingSupported(this) == BillingStatus.SUPPORTED)
    {
    (...)
        ((Button) alertRoot.findViewById(R.id.alert_billing_yes))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPurchase(BillingElement.CATALOG[number].sku);
                        alert.cancel();
                }
            });
    }
    else
    {
      (...)
      //Purchase Alert Invisible
    }
}

public void requestPurchase(String itemId) 
{
    Log.d("Parent Activity:", "Request Purchase: "+itemId);
    BillingController.requestPurchase(getApplicationContext(), itemId, true, null);
}
```

In this code I always check if a device is Online and if In-App Billing is supported.
It seems that the IMarketBillingService from Google In-App Billing throws RemoteException
and it is catched in robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary in BillingService class:

```
private void runRequest(BillingRequest request){
    try {
        long requestId = request.run(mService);
        BillingController.onRequestSent(requestId, request);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Remote billing service crashed");
        Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Caused by: "+e.getCause());

        // TODO: Retry?
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me why the RemoteException is thrown? And how to 
handle it? I've made lots of test but on my devices the In-app billing always works properly. What's more interesting on these devices where the RemoteException is thrown, it happens only sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in robotmedias implementation, you just have to rebind the service to your activity.

hpique fixed it (and some other bugs) in his fork: https://github.com/hpique/AndroidBillingLibrary/commit/a62593764172d0fd650b1dca1d15c59e79aecd49

have a look at https://github.com/hpique/AndroidBillingLibrary